# How to make text in QLineEdit widget make it set as header in a QTableView?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to set the text of the horizontal headers in my QTableView using user typed text in several QLineEdit widgets. I'm new to model-view programming and Qt framework so I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but what I've got working so far is that in my MainWindow class the widget with the QLineEdits is set as the central widget and then .text() is called on all the QLineEdits. The result is passed to a list and the list of strings is passed as parameter to my model class (QAbstractTableModel). In the model I call headerData() function to display the strings in the right column headers. However since the QLineEdits are empty initially nothing is shown. Now when I try changing the text in the QLineEdit it does not update the headers and thus makes the headers stay empty. Which signals and slots should I use to connect QLineEdit with my model?
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no source code, I just give you my opinion based on my previous experience. There are two ways to implement signal and slots. One is you can have several "returnPressed" signal for all the lineEdits and connect it to one slots, which we can name it "retrieve_all_line_edits", to obtain all the text from your LineEdits. Every time you press the return no matter which lineEdit you are in, it always goes though all the lineEdits. Pseducode here:

```
lineEdit1.returnPressed.connect(retrieve_all_line_edits)
lineEdit2.returnPressed.connect(retrieve_all_line_edits)
....

def retrieve_all_line_edits(self):
    text1 = lineEdit.text()
    text2 = lineEdit.text()
    ...
    tableHeader = [text1, text2...]
    table_header_update(tableHeader)
```

The other is you can have a button with a "clicked" signal, and do the same retrieving thing as the first one.

```
updateButton.clicked.connect(retrieve_all_line_edits)
```

The retrieve_all_line_edits is as the same as above.

Sorry for using python to explain this.

Comment: Thank you very much, so stupid of me to not think about this, ive been working on this whole day so mind little foggy... also im writing it in python so especially thanks for giving short python example.

Comment: I've been thinking a bit and stumbled upon another problem. Now that I have done this, how do I pass these new values to my model so it can update in my QTableView?

Answer (score 0):

As I said that I haven't used QTableView before, I can't precisely answer your question. But I have googled this, and it might be model.appendRow() or model.insertRow() or itemDelegate. If it is still not working, I suggest you to try QTableWidget instead.

To update your QTableView widget, whatever you use Qt Creator or Qt Designer or you write your UI by hands, you definitely have a UI class and an updating UI action class separately. For your UI class, it might seems like this:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.tableView = QTableView()
```

and inside your updating UI class, you could have:

```
class UpdateUI(object):
     def __init__(self, parent = None):
         super(UpdateUI, self).__init__()
         self.ui = Ui_MainWindow() #This from your UI class
         self.ui.setupUi(self)  #Initialize your UI
         self.signal_connect() #a self-written function that handle signal and slots

     def signal_connect(self)
         self.ui.updateButton.clicked.connect(self.update_table_view) 
         #or you could have lineEdits with return pressed signal as what I explained in previous answer.

     def update_table_view(self):
         #get all the texts first
         data = self.retrieve_all_line_edit()

         #update your table view, you have to fill this bit of code by yourself. I just give you an example here.
         self.ui.tableView.appendRow(data)
```

You can do all the actions to your UI components through self.ui, which is the instance of your UI class.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know which qt functions I can use to fill the table columns. How can I pass this new list of strings to my model so that it can update?